# Change a string with sed

Tags: sed

After using a filter to get a list of process like the next one:

```
FOO_AAAAA_00001
FOO_BBBBB_00001
FOO_ABABAB_0000
FOO_ABCCDAA_00
FOO_12345678_0
FOO_JJJ_00001
FOO_VLLLL_00001
FOO_KKAKAA_00001
```

The string is cut when the lenght excedes a certain number. I need to change the last part of the name of the process for another script that uses that name. The problem is that names ends in 00001 .

I have tried something like

```
[...]|sed 's/000/00001/g[...]
```

but the problem is obvious. It changes the correct strings too. My question is, there's a way to be able to use sed to make the change correctly when the chain is 0,00,000 to 0001 without altering the other ones?

Let's supose i have the above list:

```
FOO_AAAAA_00001
FOO_BBBBB_00001
FOO_ABABAB_0000
FOO_ABCCDAA_00
FOO_12345678_0
FOO_JJJ_00001
FOO_VLLLL_00001
FOO_KKAKAA_00001
```

First and last ones are correct. I need to get something like :

```
FOO_AAAAA_00001
FOO_BBBBB_00001
FOO_ABABAB_00001
FOO_ABCCDAA_00001
FOO_12345678_00001
FOO_JJJ_00001
FOO_VLLLL_00001
FOO_KKAKAA_00001
```

Thanks

Comment: Please paste example output: it isn't entirely clear what you want to achieve...

Comment: Edited There's a example of what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally

```
virt01@virt01:~$ sed 's/_0*$/_00001/g' some.txt
somestring_oooo_00001
somestring_oooo_00001
somestring_oooo_00001
virt01@virt01:~$
```

Exactly for your data

```
virt01@virt01:~$ cat some.txt
FOO_AAAAA_00001
FOO_BBBBB_00001
FOO_ABABAB_0000
FOO_ABCCDAA_00
FOO_12345678_0
FOO_JJJ_00001
FOO_VLLLL_00001
FOO_KKAKAA_00001
virt01@virt01:~$ sed 's/_0*$/_00001/g' some.txt
FOO_AAAAA_00001
FOO_BBBBB_00001
FOO_ABABAB_00001
FOO_ABCCDAA_00001
FOO_12345678_00001
FOO_JJJ_00001
FOO_VLLLL_00001
FOO_KKAKAA_00001
virt01@virt01:~$
```

Comment: Not worked. Need to change all the 0s lower than 4 to 0000 and add 1 to the end: 0->0001 ; 00->0001; 000->0001

Comment: @JesusCepeda Its working . I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

This will substitute the third occurrence in pattern-space of the longest possible match for 0 or more not-underscore characters for the string *`00001`*.

```sh
 sed 's/[^_]*/00001/3' <in >out
```